# Get correct indentation in Resharper for object and array initializers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coding-style, formatting, resharper

Right now resharper formats our code like this:

```
private readonly List<Folder> folders = new List<Folder>
                                        {
                                            new Folder()
                                        };
```

but I want it to look like this:

```
private readonly List<Folder> folders = new List<Folder>
{
    new Folder()
};
```

I've been messing with the options a lot, but can't seem to get them right. Can you help?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747351/custom-brace-formatting-with-resharper

Comment: Clearly and objectively the only sane layout </troll>

Answer (score 43):

I had the same issue with anonymous delegates. The fix for anonymous delegate formatting is [here](http://blog.excastle.com/2007/02/07/resharper-day-7-code-formatting/):

> I did finally find the way to fix
>   this. The options for formatting
>   anonymous methods are spread across
>   two separate pages in ReSharper
>   options: Braces Layout and Other. The
>   “don’t indent a ridiculous amount” is
>   on the Other page, and it’s called
>   “Indent anonymous method body”. Turn
>   it off, and set the brace option to
>   “At end of line”, and you get
>   something much nicer:

But i'm not sure about the instance declaration collection formatting i'm afraid. :(

Comment: Oh man I accidentally logged in under a new account and can't log in! I would totally accept this answer otherwise! - Harry

Answer (score 17):

I just had a fight with this today.
Go to ReSharper\Options\Languages\C#\Formatting Style\Other

Scroll to the bottom of the list and uncheck "Indent array, object, and collection initializer block"

That did the trick for me.

Comment: Partially solved this problem for me. I say partially because there still is some indentation left, although not that much (4 spaces to be more precise). +1.

Answer (score 11):

I also had to uncheck ReSharper\Options\Languages\C#\Formatting Style\Other --> Align Multiline Constructs and uncheck "Array, object and collection initializer" along with the other answers provided here.

Answer (score 1):

For R# 8 there is a setting exactly for this purpose in Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Braces Layout -> Array and object initializer.

"At the next line (BSD style)" is the one which this thread asks for.