# Custom Brace formatting with Resharper

Tags: c#, resharper, indentation, auto-indent

I'm using Resharper 4.5 and I need custom formatting of braces when writing an array or object initializer. Resharper supports some styles:

*Gnu Style:*

```
int[] array = new int[]  
                  {  
                      1, 2, 3  
                  }
```

but I need:

```
int[] array = new int[] 
{  
    1, 2, 3  
}
```

Is there any way to customize this templates?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can customize ReSharper to do just that, you'll need to do the following (All in **ReSharper -> Options -> C# -> Formatting Style**):

1. In **Braces Layout**, set *Array and
   object initializer* to **At Next
   line (BSD Style)**.
2. In **Other**, make sure that *Continuous line indent multiplier* is set to **1**.
3. In **Other**, make sure that *Indent array, object and collection initializer block* is **unchecked**.

You should get the style you want.

Comment: Too bad someone can't mark this as the correct answer because it obviously is.

Comment: No, this isn't a solution. This setting doesn't put the first brace on the next line.

Comment: This needs a step 4: In ''Other'', make sure that 'Indent array, object and collection initializer block' is ''unchecked''.

Comment: this worked perfectly for me; this has always bugged me so your answer is very much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Any other idea here? I set my resharper as you described, but still having the ugly code here :/

Comment: Check the answer by @mbx for more recent versions.

Comment: In Resharper 8, for step 3, the first word "Indent" was removed.  So you need to look for  "Array, object and collection initializer block" and uncheck that.

Comment: If you prefer this style for `Array, object and collection initializer`, there's also an option for `Anonymous method body` which you probably want to uncheck too.

Answer (score 9):

As of R#7.1 some Option attributes were changed:

1. In **Braces Layout**, set *Array and object initializer* to **At Next line (BSD Style)**.
2. In **Other**, make sure that *Continuous line indent multiplier* is set to **1**.

like in older versions and

1. In **Other**, at *Align Multiline Constructs* make sure that **Array, object and collection initializer** is unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

This article seems to have an answer similar to what you're looking for:

[ReSharper: Fixing array and object initializer indentation](http://hmemcpy.com/2009/04/resharper-fixing-array-object-initializer-indentation/)

Answer (score 0):

(continuation of previous answers by @igal and @mbx)

As of R# 2017.1 (and possibly earlier versions), do the following:

1. In **Formatting Style -> Braces Layout**, set *Array and object initializer* to **At Next line (BSD Style)**
2. In **Formatting Style -> Other -> Indentation**, make sure that *Continuous line indent multiplier* is set to **1**
3. In **Formatting Style -> Other -> Align Multiline Constructs**, make sure that *Array, object and collection initializer* is **unchecked**. You may also want to uncheck *Anonymous method body* if that conforms to the same style.

Answer (score -4):

as far as i know you cant, Resharper comes with predefined styles, but maybe if you create your own live template and set it the way you want it will works.

hope this helps.

Comment: it seems you really can't....live template does something else though, has no effect on code formatting.