# How to change the formatting of the "Use Object Initializer" refactoring in Resharper?

Tags: c#-3.0, formatting, resharper-4.5, object-initializers

When I refactor the following line:

```
Employee e = new Employee();
e.First = "Frank";
e.Last = "Rizzo";
```

using Resharper's "Use Object Initializer", I get the following:

```
Employee e = new Employee
             {
                 First = "Frank",
                 Last = "Rizzo"
             };
```

I really hate this type of formatting because with longer object names and variables it just gets out of control.  How can I get Resharper to do the following?

```
Employee e = new Employee
{
    First = "Frank",
    Last = "Rizzo"
};
```

Comment: I wonder who came up with this idea in the first place. No one in their right mind would indent initializers like that.

Comment: I have it on good authority that it was someone in their left mind.

Comment: no no don't change the Resharper default settings, it's perfect :-)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747351/custom-brace-formatting-with-resharper

Comment: Here are some useful Resharper formatting settings…

http://daniellang.net/5-resharper-settings-for-c4-coding/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can get very close to what you want in Resharper 4.5.

Resharper>Options

Languages>C#>Formatting Style>Other

under Other uncheck "Indent array, object and collection initializer block."

Comment: Using this with Version 5 gives 1 tab indent instead of 0. better than nothing...

Comment: found answer to that on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747351/custom-brace-formatting-with-resharper

Comment: Does anyone have an answer for ReSharper 7.1.2? It is already unchecked but still indents wrongly.

Answer (score 3):

In Resharper 7 this option is here:

Resharper / Option / C# / Formatting Style / Braces Layout
set Array and object initializer to: "At next line (BSD style)"

Comment: I don't know about RS7, but in RS6 that's quite definitely not the right place — the setting in Formatting > Other determines whether the indent set here is relative to the start of the line or to the initializer statement. The live preview on each setting will show you what I mean better than words can explain it :)

Comment: @David Krmpotic is correct about RS7, and RS8 has it in the same place.

Comment: In Reshaper 8 the setting to not indent the object initializer is Resharper / Option / C# / Formatting Style / Other / Align Multiline Constructs / Array, object and collection initializer

Answer (score 1):

In R# 2018.2.3 This is in:

`ReSharper` -> `Options` -> `Code Editing` -> `C#` -> `Formatting Style` -> `Line Breaks And Wrapping` -> `Arrangement of Initializers`

There is multiple settings you can play with there, namely:

- Keep existing arrangement of initializers
- Max object and collection initializer elements on a single line