# Visual Studio/ReSharper code formatting - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, resharper

When creating a new type using the object initialiser syntax, Visual Studio automatically moves the braces to align with the type after the new keyword.

Like this

```
MyType myType = new MyType
                    {

                    };
```

However, I would prefer it not to do this and instead leave it like so

```
MyType myType = new MyType
{

};
```

Any ideas how to do this - I've been through all the Visual Studio formatting options and can't find one that is appropriate

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my [most popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747351/custom-brace-formatting-with-resharper/819393#819393) here:

1. In **Braces Layout**, set *Array and
   object initializer* to **At Next
   line (BSD Style)**.
2. In **Other**, make sure that *Continuous line indent multiplier* is set to **1**.
3. In **Other**, make sure that *Indent array, object and collection initializer block* is **unchecked**.

You will have the style that you want!

Answer (score 3):

You will find this in Resharper options.
Go to `ReSharper -> Options -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Braces Layout -> "Array And Object Initialization"`. But I am not sure if ReSharper allows such formatting.

Comment: thanks -that seems like the most appropriate option, I agree. However, I have tried that one by changing it to be the same as a method declararion (No Space BSD). However, as soon as I hit return between the object initialisation braces {}, it immediately indents them up to after the new keyword

Comment: Unfortunately ReSharper do not have style which You want to apply. You can only choose from those which are available there now :/.