# Resharper overindents my code

Tags: c#, resharper

I would like resharper to indent my code the following way:

```
var modification = shortUrlIndexCollection.FindAndModify
(
    Query.Or
    (
        Query.And
        (
            Query.EQ("_id", "Index"),
            Query.EQ("LockId", Guid.Empty)
        ),
        Query.LT("UnlockOn", now)
    ),
    SortBy
        .Null,
    Update
        .Set("LockId", guid)
        .Set("UnlockOn", now + reserveDuration),
    true
);
```

But instead it formats my code the following way:

```
var modification = shortUrlIndexCollection.FindAndModify
    (
        Query.Or
            (
                Query.And
                    (
                        Query.EQ("_id", "Index"),
                        Query.EQ("LockId", Guid.Empty)
                    ),
                Query.LT("UnlockOn", now)
            ),
        SortBy
            .Null,
        Update
            .Set("LockId", guid)
            .Set("UnlockOn", now + reserveDuration),
        true
    );
```

According to [Custom Brace formatting with Resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747351/custom-brace-formatting-with-resharper) I have already tried the `continuous line indent multiplier` option, but it gives wrong results...

Comment: Have you tried Open ReSharper > Options > [Your language] > Formatting style > Other and try playing with options in sections called "Indentation" and "Other"

Comment: I've tried inverting every possible switch in every category separately just to find out the setting that affects this indentation problem, as far as I found `continuous line indent multiplier` changes behaviour but doesn't help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to format `(` and `)` the way you want it in ReSharper 7.1 or lower. We're working on implementing a new indenting system in 8.0, which would give you a better control on layout of () and [].

Answer (score 4):

Try [Resharper 7.1](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/11/resharper-71-is-available/) it has fixed the indenting of chained methods.

Just tryed it with my stylecop settings and the formatting becomes:

```
shortUrlIndexCollection.FindAndModify(
                Query.Or(
                    Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", "Index"), Query.EQ("LockId", Guid.Empty)), Query.LT("UnlockOn", now)),
                SortBy.Null,
                Update.Set("LockId", guid).Set("UnlockOn", now + reserveDuration),
                true);
```

Not what you want.

Comment: Do I need some specific setup for that?

Comment: probably, thought it would work out of the box, but can't get it to work just now.

Comment: It seems that they haven't fixed that for sure... :)))