# How can I set Resharper to indent wrapped lines by exactly one tab?

Tags: c#, resharper, word-wrap, indentation

How can I set Resharper to indent wrapped C# lines by exactly one tab for lines that wrap around (except the first line of course)?

If I set the continuous line indent multiplier to zero, I get this:

```
This is a really long 
statement that wraps around
and takes up three lines of code;
```

If I set the continuous line indent multiplier to 1, I get this stair step effect:

```
This is a really long
    statement that wraps around
        and takes up three lines of code;
```

What I really want is this (plain old hanging indent style):

```
This is a really long
    statement that wraps around
    and takes up three lines of code;
```

Dmitry Osinovskiy hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387385/resharper-overindents-my-code) that Resharper 8 might be able to do this, but I have 8.0.2 and I still don't see a way to do it.

Comment: I really need this too. While refactoring some coworkers' long lines of code that's already nested deeply, resharpen often breaks after every word creating a nightmarish diagonal. There must be a way to keep all indentations after the first line aligned.

Comment: How is this still not a thing that Resharper can do, even in Resharper 9?