# How to auto-format a line that has been broken in many lines

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, resharper

An old code formatting (probably done by Resharper) has turned to code like this:

```cs
    private static readonly DataLoadOptions loadVibItemsForPatientQueryOptions = (new Func<DataLoadOptions>(() =>                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                                                                                                               var
                                                                                                                        ret
                                                                                                                            =
                                                                                                                            new DataLoadOptions
                                                                                                                                ();
                                                                                                                    ret
                                                                                                                        .
                                                                                                                        LoadWith
                                                                                                                        <
                                                                                                                            PrescriptionEntity
                                                                                                                            >
                                                                                                                        (pe
                                                                                                                         =>
                                                                                                                         pe
                                                                                                                             .
                                                                                                                             TreatmentEntity);
```

It is rather to the right due to the block being part of the function being defined at the end of the top line being at the end of the width limit. Maybe I could improve this on the settings for Resharper code formatting (or VS).

But if I move manually the code to the left, is there an automatic way to re-format the line-broken code to look something like this:

```cs
    private static readonly DataLoadOptions loadVibItemsForPatientQueryOptions = (new Func<DataLoadOptions>(() =>
    {
        var ret = new DataLoadOptions();
        ret.LoadWith<PrescriptionEntity>(pe => pe.TreatmentEntity);
```

Comment: If you still using the ReSharper you can click Ctrl+Alt+F to run the autoformat dialog.

Comment: I am and Code Cleanup or Reformat Code did not fix it.

Comment: You also can try to reset Resharper settings.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747351/custom-brace-formatting-with-resharper/819393#819393), my most upvoted ReSharper answer :)

Comment: I had not changed those ReSharper settings, and they are as @IgalTabachnik suggests. So that still doesn't do it for me.. But good to know about them :)