# ReSharper LINQ extension method formatting

Tags: linq, formatting, resharper, extension-methods, resharper-6.0

I'm struggling with Resharpers formatting. 
Consider the following Code:

```
product.Resources.Where(x => x.Tracked).Pipe(y =>
                                             {
                                                 //Action       
                                             });
```

How can I tell ReSharper to indent the part in the curly braces and the curly braces itself only a little bit? I've tried several Resharper formatting settings but none had any effect in this case.

### Edit:

I would like to have a format similar to this:

```
product.Resources.Where(x => x.Tracked).Pipe(y =>
    {
        //Action       
    });
```

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519755/get-correct-indentation-in-resharper

Comment: Thanks, it's looking much better now.

Comment: @jessehouwing - you should submit that as an answer so he can mark it and close this question.

Comment: I tried but it keeps converting it to a comment... due to the small size.. Let me copy over the details from the other question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/819393/736079

You can customize ReSharper to do just that, you'll need to do the following (All in ReSharper -> Options -> C# -> Formatting Style):

- In Braces Layout, set Array and object initializer to At Next line (BSD Style).
- In Other, make sure that Continuous line indent multiplier is set to 1.
- In Other, make sure that Indent array, object and collection initializer block is unchecked.

You should get the style you want.

Comment: Very useful. I found out that also "Anonymous method declaration" is best set to BSD style.